# User control with GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, user-controls

I have one user control with a single GridView. I have declared the datatable, dtResult as static to get it from the page. Now, i have one method e.g.

```
protected void BindGridView()
{
    gvMyGrid.DataSource = dtResult; //this dtResult varies depending on the call of publicly exposed method of this user control.
    gvMyGrid.DataBind();
}

public void GetResult(string text)
{
    dtResult = new DataTable();
    dtResult = Getdata(text); //This method returns the collection by filtering it with text
    BindGridView();
}

public void GetResult()
{
    dtResult = new DataTable();
    dtResult = Getdata();
    BindGridView();
}
```

Now I can easily call any of the method to bind the result but it's really hard for me to bind the same after paging. How to remember the last called method as it could be any of them and I have to handle this automatically as it is inside a user control.

Please advise.

Comment: Don't make it `static`. That will share it across all requests which can cause locks at the best. That's not way you should use, instead load it always when you need it. If ViewState is enabled(default) you only need it `if(!IsPostBack)` and when you change the source(f.e. on sorting or paging). **Edit**: _"dtResult as static to get it from the page"_ So the reason was that you want to access it in your UserControl? Then provide a property `DataSource` in your control and let it be set from the page. That's the correct way because the page is the controller not the UC.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I got an idea and tried to implement the same using a public prooperty named as DataSource of the user control. Now the problem is while trying to change the page index my datasource became null. Tried to put that into ViewState but it will become huge as the datasource contains List<myClass>. Again your advise required.

Comment: Don't put datasources in ViewState, if you need to change the a GridView-PageIndex load the datasource from the database again as commented above.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But the problem is that I have populated the Datasource from the calling page with the logic to get the data which may differ from one page to another and I don't have that same logic in my user control to reload the datasource from there again. This is where I faced the problem earlier and put the data into static DataTable.

Comment: Instead of a static table, you can always access the real instance of your page from the UC in this way: `PageName p = (PageName) this.Page;`. But it's still better to let the page "inject" the source, otherwise you are hard-wiring this usercontrol with this page which is not desired. Read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication
I don't understand the problem, if different pages have different logic to get the data, they will also pass a different datasource to the UC which is fine, isn't it?